# VBA: Copy data from one workbook to another Subscript Out of Range

Tags: vba, loops, subtraction

I am trying to copy data from one workbook to another but am getting Subcript out of range after it completes the copy.

This is the code:

```
Sub TransferCorps()

Dim wbSource As Workbook

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("H:\Carol Facklam\SL Entities.xlsx")
Sheets("Temp").Range("A1") = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

wbSource.Close (True)

End Sub

'This is the data that is copied
00SLH   Saint Lukes Hospital
00SLS   Saint Lukes South Hospital
0SLNH   Saint Lukes Northland Hospital
SLHLS   St Lukes Hospital Lees Summit
00CMH   Cushing Memorial Hospital
CRITT   Crittenton
0HOSP   Saint Lukes Homecare Hospice
0MPIA   Medical Plaza Imaging Assoc
SLCHS   SL College of Health Sciences
SLRTL   Saint Lukes Radiation Therapy-Liberty LL
00AUA   Advanced Urological Associates
0SLCC   SLCC, Inc.
0SL15   Saint Lukes Neighborhood Clinic LLC
000MG   Saint Lukes Medical Group
0SLPS   SL Physician Specialists
```

Can you help me figure out why I'm getting this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the moment you open the Source-Workbook, it gets the active workbook. `Sheets("Temp")` will be taken from the active workbook which is probably not what you want (and I assume that there is no "temp"-sheet in the sourceWB, causing the subscript out of range-error).

You have to tell Excel where to find the temp-Sheet. If it is the same Workbook as your Macro-Code, you could use

`thisworkbook.sheets("Temp").Range...`

else you shoud assign a Workbook-Variable `wbDest` with the destination workbook and write

`wbDest.sheets("Temp").Range...`

Comment: I'm inserting the data in whatever spreadsheet I'm running the macro in. How would I address that data?

Comment: As written, if the macro is stored in the workbook where you want to copy the data to, use `thisworkbook`, If it is the sheet on the screen, you could you `activeWorkbook` - before opening your SourceWorkbook (`set destWB = activeWorkbook` or `set destWS = activeworksheet`). If you know the name of the destWb, use `Workbooks("MyWbName"`). There are a lot of ways (and a lot of pages on the internet explaining it)

Answer (score 0):

I used the following and it worked like a charm. Thank you!

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B15").Copy ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Range("A1")